# How to find folder size within VSS

Tags: vss

I have a repository in VSS and I need to find the size of individual folders inside the VSS. Currently I am checking out each of the folder and then checking its size.

Is there any way using which I can easily find the folder size inside the VSS?

P.S. VSS - Visual Sourcesafe

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do that via VSS Client. You may want to perform a recursive get on the project you'd like to see the folder sizes of and check the info from the Windows Explorer.